# PHP-MySQL: Limit data with a specific characters

Tags: php, mysql, date, character, limit

I researched the forum but could not find a solution.

I have a date in my DB and date format is not like `Y-m-d H:i`. And the table is not set as date. I need to fetch the date from db but I just need `Y-m-d`.
My date format like: `9.12.2014 18:34`. I just need `9.12.2014`. I want my query to stop when it sees the blank/space. I'm fine with the `d.m.Y` format.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

```
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$user = strstr($email, '@', true); // after PHP 5.3.0
echo $user; // name
```

Comment: You might want to tag this as php.

Answer (score 0):

This should account for most scenarios; you will get the whole string if there are no spaces:

```
SELECT IF(INSTR(field, ' ')=0, field, LEFT(field, INSTR(field, ' ')-1))
FROM the_table
;
```

Comment: Thanks Uueerdo,

My query is: `$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  'orders' WHERE  'dReceievedDate' LIKE '%$q%' AND Source='channel' AND cCountry='UK' AND status!='1' ORDER BY OrderNumber LIMIT 100");
  while ($details = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {`

and fetching the date like: `'.$details['dReceievedDate'].'`

I need to split the date after the query. And the date is changing like ; `15.9.2014`  or `7.9.2014` . I don't know if I can use substr. I think i can not.